# want to replace the textview with the given number in edittext using sharedpreference

Tags: android

Sir.. I have a textview in which is **clickable** in  **activity_main.xml** and on click of that textview I'll move to **registration.xml** and there i will give phone number in EditText, I want to save that number using sharedpreference and i need to get the number to display on previous **activity_main.xml** on that textView which i clicked before.When I click logout Button the number should erase and previous textview should replace. Please some one help me clearly.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tasknumberchange.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:text="@string/welcome"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/clickForRegistration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/welcome"
    android:layout_below="@id/welcome"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:onClick="RegisterHere"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="@string/click_text"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/clickForRegistration"
    android:layout_below="@+id/clickForRegistration"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/clickForRegistration"
    android:src="@drawable/line"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:onClick="LogOut"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/save_styles"
    android:text="@string/logout"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.tasknumberchange;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView txt1,txt2;

    public static SharedPreferences sh;
    public static Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.clickForRegistration);

        //txt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.replace);
        sh = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
        txt1.setText(sh.getString("PhoneNo",""));
        txt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegistrationPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }

    public void LogOut(View view)
    {
        sh=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor sh_editor = sh.edit();
        sh_editor.clear();
        sh_editor.commit();
    }
}
```

**registration.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phoneDetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/phone"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/phone_number"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/savePhoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/save_styles"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**RegistrationPage.java**

```
package com.example.tasknumberchange;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RegistrationPage extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    Button save;
    EditText phoneNumber;
    String st_phoneNumber;
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    public static final String Phone="PhoneNo";
     SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);

        phoneNumber=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phoneDetails);
        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.savePhoneNumber);
        sharedpreferences=getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                st_phoneNumber=phoneNumber.getText().toString();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(Phone, st_phoneNumber);
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(RegistrationPage.this,"Thanks",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("MyNumber",st_phoneNumber);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
          return true;
       }
       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
          // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
          // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

          int id = item.getItemId();

          //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
          if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
             return true;
          }
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onResume(). This function is called when the activity come back on screen. It is in this function that you will get you intent and change your text in your textview.

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT 2:

**Change your MainActivity like this:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView txt1,txt2;

public  SharedPreferences sh;
public  SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.clickForRegistration);

    //txt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.replace);
    sh = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
    if(!sh.getString("PhoneNo","").isEmpty())
        txt1.setText(sh.getString("PhoneNo",""));
    txt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegistrationPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

}

public void LogOut(View view)
{
    sh=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor sh_editor = sh.edit();
    sh_editor.clear();
    sh_editor.commit();

    //Start all over again..!!

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent1);
    finish();
}

}
```

I have tried this and working perfectly for me. Hope this helps you too :)

Comment: Text is not showing.. when applications opens its showing empty text..!!

Comment: As per your instructions i posted my code.!! Please check my above code and see what i'm expecting..!!

Comment: in MainActivity I'm trying to clear sharedpreference by the name function LogOut but exact logic i'm not getting due to i'm new to android..!!

Comment: see my edit i have made some changes in your `MainActivity` and i got it working..!!! :)

Comment: Thank you..!! After logging out how to clear sharedpreference and back to same clickable text?

Comment: can i get your email id? i got some issues and need to ask you so

Answer (score 0):

Just change your main activity by below, if it is working fine then try to understand code and let me know if any issue.

```
      package com.example.tasknumberchange;

      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.content.Context;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.content.SharedPreferences;
      import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
      import android.widget.TextView;

      public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            TextView txt1,txt2;

            public static SharedPreferences sh;
            public static Editor editor;

          @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
              txt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.clickForRegistration);

             sh = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
             txt1.setText(sh.getString("PhoneNo",""));
             txt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegistrationPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
           }

       });

   }

   public void LogOut(View view)
   {
       sh=getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor sh_editor = sh.edit();
       sh_editor.remove("PhoneNo");
       sh_editor.clear();
       sh_editor.commit();

       txt1.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.click_text));

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

     setValues();
    }

    public void setValues()
    {
       sh = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
       txt1.setText(sh.getString("PhoneNo",""));
    }


}
```